# cc1plus: unrecognized command line option warning on any other warning

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a strange behavior of g++ that it shows a warning about unrecognized command line option, when any other warning is shown.

Example:

```
struct Foo{virtual int bar() = 0;};
struct Bar:public Foo{int bar() {return 0;} };

int main(){}
```

Compiling with `g++-5 -Wsuggest-override -Wno-c99-extensions -std=c++11 a.cpp` or even `g++-5 -Wsuggest-override -Wno-c99-extensions a.cpp` shows:

```
a.cpp:2:27: warning: ‘virtual int Bar::bar()’ can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]
 struct Bar:public Foo{int bar() {return 0;} };
                           ^
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-c99-extensions’
```

ADDITION: There is no warning/error when I compile with `g++-5 -Wno-c99-extensions a.cpp` hence that option passes CMAKEs check using `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG`

This bothers me quite a lot, as we use Werror but with exceptions via Wno-error=... It then bails out when any of the (non-error) warnings is shown with the "unrecognized command line option"

Is this known/expected? How can it be prevented?

Comment: For the downvoters: Could you please add a comment why you downvoted? Then I could improve the question. As I just noticed, I forgot to mention that the flag itself does not throw a warning/error

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with gcc5. Likewise, I only want CMake to use the warning silence flags when the compiler accepts them. The  "simply remove it from your build command answer" isn't helpful when (for example) newer GCC versions accept the flag (and *need* it to silence a warning) but older ones only show them in the presence of another warning.

Comment: But the "test for the positive form" is the correct solution to the cmake aspect of this. Yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want warnings about unrecognised command-line options, don't use unrecognised command-line options: `-Wno-c99-extensions` has never been a valid GCC option (I believe it's a clangism). Simply remove it from your build command.

As for why the warning is only emitted when you have *another* warning present, this behaviour seems counter-intuitive but [it is actually deliberate and documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#wnowarning):

> **The warning "unrecognized command-line option" is not given for -Wno-foo**
>
> Since GCC 4.4, and as explained in the GCC manual: *when an unrecognized warning option is requested (`-Wunknown-warning`), GCC emits a diagnostic stating that the option is not recognized. However, if the `-Wno-` form is used, the behavior is slightly different: no diagnostic is produced for `-Wno-unknown-warning` unless other diagnostics are being produced. This allows the use of new `-Wno-` options with old compilers, but if something goes wrong, the compiler warns that an unrecognized option is present.* (See PR28322 for the history of this change)
>
> This might break configure tests that check for `-Wno-foo` options. The solution is to either test for the positive form (`-Wfoo`) or test using a testcase that triggers some other warning.

There are in fact a few results on Google of mailing list threads where software developers have faced this "problem", specifically with CMake, and made trivial fixes to their build scripts to "fix" it.

Comment: Seems like you are right. I'm using CMAKEs CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG before adding it to avoid checking for specific compilers. Seems I have forgotten to add to the question that there is no warning/error about that if there is not an other error. So the real question is: Why do I get nothing when there is no warning, but an additional warning/error when there is a (unrelated) warning?

Comment: @Flamefire: Who cares? You're using a non-existent flag. Why attempt to rationalise about its behaviour? Simply stop using it.

Comment: When you use CMake for multi-platform/multi-compiler projects you would care. Of course you can check for each compiler and add flags depending on that compiler and its version. But this gets easily very large and error-prone. That is one of the use cases for `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG` but that fails due to inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: I expected some kind of error for wrongly invoking the program like it is done when you forgot to pass the input files. The flag itself exists, but it is not supported/known by gcc, hence I expected `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG` to return false here (from its docu: "Check whether the CXX compiler supports a given flag.") but it doesn't because gcc just swallows the unsupported flag. Is it that wrong to expect any message when you pass a non-understood flag to a program? What if you simply had misspelled it? And it works in other cases...

Comment: @Flamefire: _"The flag itself exists, but it is not supported/known by gcc"_ This is a contradiction.

Comment: @Flamefire: Of course it would be ideal if the entire command were rejected due to the presence of the non-existent flag, and it would be slightly less ideal but still preferred if you got the resulting warning consistently (instead of just when some other warning were emitted) .... but I still don't see the point in spending time trying to change this behaviour when the solution is to write the correct command in the first place, that's all. **For what it's worth, since you actually got me curious, the behaviour is explained here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#wnowarning :)**

Comment: Ok, correct: "The flag itself exists [in other compilers], but it is not supported/known by gcc". As mentioned, writing the "correct command" is not trivial in the presence of many (possibly unknown) compilers and versions, so an automatic test, if that flag is recognized, is required. So thank you very much for finding the missing piece of information on the difference of `-Wfoo` and `W-no-foo`. This helps a lot! :)